# Creating a GraphQLObjectType with an indexable field signature?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm currently in the process of transforming a REST API into GraphQL, but I've hit a bit of a snag in one of the endpoints.

Currently, this endpoint returns an object who's keys can be an unlimited set of strings, and whos values all match a certain shape.

So, as a rudimentary example, I have this situation...

```
// response
{
    foo: { id: 'foo', count: 3 },
    bar: { id: 'bar', count: 6 },
    baz: { id: 'baz', count: 1 },
}
```

Again, the keys are not known at runtime and can be an unlimited set of strings.

In TypeScript, for example, this sort of situation is handled by creating an interface using an indexable field signature, like so...

```
interface Data {
    id: string;
    count: number;
}

interface Response {
    [key: string]: Data;
}
```

So, my question is: Is this sort of thing possible with graphql? How would I go about creating a type/schema for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that one solution can be usage of `JSON.stringify()` method

```js
exampleQuery: {
    type: GraphQLString,
    resolve: (root, args, context) => {
        let obj = {
            foo: { id: 'foo', count: 3 },
            bar: { id: 'bar', count: 6 },
            baz: { id: 'baz', count: 1 }
        };

        return JSON.stringify(obj);
    }
}
```

Then, after retrieving the result of GraphQL query you could use `JSON.parse(result)` (in case the part performing the query is also written in JavaScript - otherwise you would have to use equivalent method of other language to parse the incoming `JSON` response).

Disadvantage of such a solution is that you do not have the possibility to choose what fields of `obj` you want to retrieve from the query, but, as you said, the returning object can have unlimited set of strings that probably are not known on the front end of the application, so there is no need to choose it's keys, am I right?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Sorry for the delay!

I ended up going with something like this for one particular route, but also ended up just transforming a similar response to an array in the resolve method of the type.

In other words...

`resolve: myObj => Object.keys(myObj).map(key => ({ key, value: myObj[key] }));`